# plugin for helping writing python program on notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++

Are there any plugin that can help writing Python program on Notepad++. Currently, I have to manually control the indentation. For example, I need to click the "space" four times to ensure the indentation is right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change your tab you need to go in notepad ++ Menu Settings > Preferences... then select Tab Settings Then select python in the Tab Settings box and uncheck Use default value and check Replace by space.

If you want a more usefull IDE for Python, you might want to consider another ide. for example eclipse with the pydev plugin and django plungin. Erik is nice too.